# How to define a dependency to a specific package of a third party jar. I do not want all packages of the Jar just few specific packages

Tags: maven, gradle

Let's suppose I have a 3rd party jar **commons-lib-1.1.0.jar**  that contains 3 packages like com.web, com.service and com.dao. I only want com.dao package in my project. I am referring it in my Gradle build as a dependency.

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.testorg:commons-lib:1.1.0.jar'
}
```

This way I am getting whole jar (all packages), but I just want com.dao package from it.
Please help how to define a dependency to a specific package of a third party jar. Is it even possible in Gradle or Maven?

Comment: I can only speak for Maven (not Gradle), but I doubt that this is possible. Could you please explain us why you want that?

Comment: It's just the other packages contains classes that can affect my App. For example there are packages that contains REST controller that I do not want in my service (otherwise unnecessary endpoint are exposed, or unwarted Beans that require configs at initialization). Ideally 3rd party jar should be a multi-module project that creates multiple jar for say DAO module, Web module, REST/Controller module etc, but as it's not the case for me so was trying to find some solution.